# How to simulate remote host deployment with PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Some FTP clients, such as Transmit, offer an option to simulate the synchronisation between a local and a remote directory. Basically what it means is, that you get a list of files that would be changed, instead of actually moving the files.

I was hoping to find such an option in PhpStorm's Remote Host Plugin, but I searched for it to no avail. Did I overlook something, or does this not exist (yet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPStorm can sync with the deployed version if the remote host has been configured. It shows the difference and you can select what to do with each file. See [PHPStorm Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html)